# Updating apk on emulator/device without uninstalling previous version using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

My first apk has version - 1, versionCode - 100.

Second apk has version - 2, versionCode - 200. I am using same keystore for both apk's but i still get

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install.

**Note** - i want to update app not unistall and replace with new one.

Comment: You can't update an app without overwriting the installed one

Comment: unable to overwrite.

Comment: in Android Studio, when you press the Run button, its automatically install the new update with adb commands

Comment: this is for cordova

Comment: You should have mentioned it in the question <.<. I cant help in Cordova, sorry. I've edited your question

Comment: `users need to update this version. Need solution with default options. can't add shell script.` It's not clear from your question title you're talking about deploying to end users. That is what the Play Store is for, or 3rd party MDM. If you are distributing the APK directly, then if the APK is signed with the same keystore signing key and the version/build number has been incremented, the Android OS will offer to install it as an update.